# ESP32 setenv() and localtime() from UTC time string

Tags: c++, esp32, localtime, setenv

please consider following code, it compiles and run on ESP32 board:

```
    unsetenv("TZ");
    String payload = http.getString();
    payload.replace("\"", "");
    Serial.print("Payload: ");
    Serial.println(payload);
    const char* format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S";
    strptime(payload.c_str(), format,& _time);

    //debug only
    Serial.print("Chamber time(UTC): ");
    char chDate[11] = "";
    char chTime[9] = "";
    strftime(chDate, 11, "%m/%d/%Y", &_time);
    strftime(chTime, 9, "%H:%M:%S", &_time);
    Serial.print(chDate);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(chTime);

    int epoch_time = mktime(&_time);
    timeval epoch = { epoch_time, 0 };
    const timeval* tv = &epoch;
    settimeofday(tv, NULL);



    int rcode = setenv("TZ", "EST+5", 1);
    tzset();
    Serial.print("SetEnv reply");
    Serial.println(rcode);
    //VERIFICA
    struct tm now;
    getLocalTime(&now, 0);
    Serial.println(&now, " %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S (%A)");
```

producing the following output:

```
Payload: 2020-04-08T21:59:10.736+0000
Chamber time(UTC): 04/08/2020 21:59:10
SetEnv reply0
April 08 2020 21:59:10 (Wednesday)
```

I expected the last date to be a local time according to "EST+5" timezone, in this example. Infact, I followed [this](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/protocols/sntp/README.md) readme, as I am using a ESP32 board, that says:

> To set local timezone, use setenv and tzset POSIX functions. First,
>   call setenv to set TZ environment variable to the correct value
>   depending on device location. Format of the time string is described
>   in libc documentation. Next, call tzset to update C library runtime
>   data for the new time zone. Once these steps are done, localtime
>   function will return correct local time, taking time zone offset and
>   daylight saving time into account

What am I missing/doing wrong, apart from my rusty C++? Perfect solution would be to use : format like ":Europe/Rome" Thanks

Comment: @nathanoliver is tonight question better? :)

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The TZ string "EST+5" might be unknown to the OS, supported by the fact your output showed UTC time. EST and EDT have been used for US Eastern or America/New York. Assuming this is a Linux-like OS, take a look in the */usr/share/zoneinfo/* path for the zones available, or try the **tzselect** command to see if you can find the correct TZ string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me...after a bunch of pain finding solutions when I tested on my local linux machine, but did not work on the esp32

My esp32 TZ variable was initially set to a CST timezone, I wanted to read in a UTC timestamp and convert it to a PDT timezone. Here is what I did:

```
# Set timezone to UTC
setenv("TZ", "GMT0",1);
tzset();

# Read in timezone of format 2023-03-14T00:00:00.000Z
struct tm tm;
sscanf(utc_time.c_str(), "%4d-%2d-%2dT%2d:%2d:%2d",
    &tm.tm_year,
    &tm.tm_mon,
    &tm.tm_mday,
    &tm.tm_hour,
    &tm.tm_min,
    &tm.tm_sec
);

# mktime is expecting tm_year & tm_mon based off year since 1900 and months since January
tm.tm_year -= 1900;
tm.tm_mon--;

time_t epoch = mktime(&tm);

# Set to the new timezone we want & convert it
setenv("TZ","PST8PDT",1);
tzset();

struct tm* out_tm;
out_tm = localtime(&epoch);

# Print it out
char out_str[15];
strftime(out_str,sizeof(out_str),""%A, %B %d %Y %I:%M:%S"",out_tm);
Serial.printf("Converted time is: %s\n",out_str);
```

Result:

```
Before time is: 2023-03-14T00:00:00.000Z
Converted time is: Monday, March 13 2023 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence of C functions:

```
   time_t tnow;
   time(&tnow);
   struct tm when;
   errno_t ret = localtime_s(&when, &tnow);
   // struct tm *when = localtime(&tnow); // deprecated for some compilers
```

The `getLocalTime()` function is not standard C and may not honor `tzset()`.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. localtime_s is not compiling, while localtime(&tnow) works, but with same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code...Replace:

```
int rcode = setenv("TZ", "EST+5", 1);
```

with:

```
int rcode = setenv("TZ", "EST5EDT", 1);
```

or:

```
int rcode = setenv("TZ", "EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0", 1);
```